# Return list of values on ajax success in spring MVC

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am looking for returning a list of values after ajax success in spring mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAlertNotification.ftl")
 public ModelAndView getAlertNotification(HttpServletRequest request
   ){
  Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
  User user = RequestUtils.getUser(request);
  List<CardRequestNotification> Cardreqlist=cardRequestManager.cardRequestNotification(user);
  model.put("listObj", Cardreqlist);
  return new ModelAndView(new JSONView(model));

 }




$("#alertLink").click(function()
              {  var $this = j$(this);
              GtsJQuery.ajax(GtsJQuery.getContextPath()
                             + "/getAlertNotification.ftl",

                     function(data) {
                    /*  how i return Cardreqlist object list`enter code here` in here */

                   });
```

Comment: Please add your error..or wht is not working

Comment: alert(result.Cardreqlist);  is not working......
Error = undifined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are having a misunderstanding concept, if you are trying to return a ModelAndView then you need to specify the JSP file or HTML template which will be rendered, and you need the specific ModelAndView name.

But you are mixing Views and JSON, which is for AJAX calls, so i guess your code would be something more like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAlertNotification.ftl")
@ResponseBody
public List<CardRequestNotification> getAlertNotification(HttpServletRequest request) {
      Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
      User user = RequestUtils.getUser(request);
      List<CardRequestNotification> Cardreqlist = cardRequestManager.cardRequestNotification(user);
      model.put("listObj", Cardreqlist);
      return Cardreqlist;
}
```

Then in your JS code, you could do:

```
data.Cardreqlist
```